# calling javascript function from .net codebehind with a value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to call a javascript function from asp.net codebehind using onclientclick for a linkbutton. Code is like this:

```
string x = "redirecttoimagepage"+"("+ y+")";//y has an int value i need and it varies
lnkimagepage.OnClientClick = x;
```

i need to use the value y in the javascript function for using.

```
 function redirecttoimagepage(variable)
{
var strURL = "Subpages.aspx?tabID="+variable;
window.open(strURL,"_blank");
return true;
}
```

Right now, with the code i have shared, it doesnt do anything. After the link is clicked, it stays in the same page. What am i doing wrong? Appreciate all your help guys. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string x = "redirecttoimagepage"+"('"+ y+"')";
lnkimagepage.Attributes.Add("onclick",x);
```

EDITED

in addition, just noticed that `lnkimagepage` is a `LinkButton` so it will be hard to invoke `redirecttoimagepage` script as `LinkButton`s are already associated with `__doPostBack` jscript. use `HyperLink` instead of `LinkButton`

Comment: How would this be different from `OnClientClick`?

Comment: @Domenic asp.net 2.0 (and above) have a `OnClientClick` property, This is basically a shortcut for `Attributes[”onclick”]`. no differences... its just a way I got used to write a code...

Comment: OK, then my question is why is this different from the OP's code. I guess the stuff after the edit is relevant, but otherwise it does the exact same thing.

Comment: remo did missed the apostrophe, as he had `"redirecttoimagepage"+"("+ y+")"`. the right form is `"redirecttoimagepage"+"('"+ y+"')"`. test urselft the first version wil give u x equals to `redirecttoimagepage(value_of_y)` while my version gives `redirecttoimagepage('value_of_y')`. this way jscript `redirecttoimagepage` is called and `value_of_y` is passed as parameter

Comment: Ah! Damn, hard to spot those little apostrophes :P. OK, +1 it is.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to call a javascript function from asp.net codebehind using onclientclick for a linkbutton. Code is like this:

Your doing it wrong. The HTTP model is a model of requests. The page talks to the server not the other way around.

If you *truly* need a bi-directional communication channel use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)

Comment: It seems like he's doing it (conceptually right) but his explaination is ridiculous. It seems like he does not know what "to call a function" means.

Answer (score 0):

```
string x = "redirecttoimagepage"+"('"+ y+"')"; 
lnkimagepage.Attributes.Add("onclick",x);

**in javascript**
window.open("PageName.aspx");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must specify complete url with window.open not just page name.....

Comment: This is false; it works just like any other URL and can be either relative or absolute.